# Encoding data with LabelEncoder()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, classification, data-analysis

I'm having the following dataset as a csv file.

**Dataset ecoli.csv:**

```
seq_name,mcg,gvh,lip,chg,aac,alm1,alm2,class
AAT_ECOLI,0.49,0.29,0.48,0.50,0.56,0.24,0.35,cp
ACEA_ECOLI,0.07,0.40,0.48,0.50,0.54,0.35,0.44,cp
(more entries...)
ACKA_ECOLI,0.59,0.49,0.48,0.50,0.52,0.45,0.36,cp
ADI_ECOLI,0.23,0.32,0.48,0.50,0.55,0.25,0.35,cp
```

My purpose for this dataset is to apply some classification algorithms. In order to handle ecoli.csv file I'm trying to change the class column and put in as first one while seq_name column is dropped. Then I'm printing a test to search for null values. Afterwards I'm plotting with the help of sns library.

**Code before error:**

```
column_drop = 'seq_name'
dataframe = pd.read_csv('ecoli.txt', header='infer')
dataframe.drop(column_drop, axis=1, inplace=True)  # Dropping columns that I don't need
print(dataframe.isnull().sum())

plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
sns.heatmap(dataframe.corr(), annot=True)
plt.show()
```

Before the encoding, and the error I'm facing, I group the values of the dataset based on class. Finally I'm trying to encode the dataset with LabelEncoder but and an error appears:

**Error code:**

```
result = dataframe.groupby(by=("class")).sum().reset_index()
print(result)

le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
dataframe.result = le.fit_transform(dataframe.result)
print(result)
```

**Error:**

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'result'
```

***Update***: `result` is filled with the following index

```
  class    mcg    gvh    lip   chg    aac   alm1   alm2
0    cp  51.99  58.59  68.64  71.5  64.99  44.71  56.52
1    im  36.84  38.24  37.48  38.5  41.28  58.33  56.24
2   imL   1.45   0.94   2.00   1.5   0.91   1.29   1.14
3   imS   1.48   1.02   0.96   1.0   1.07   1.28   1.14
4   imU  25.41  16.06  17.32  17.5  19.56  26.04  26.18
5    om  13.45  14.20  10.12  10.0  14.78   9.25   6.11
6   omL   3.49   2.56   5.00   2.5   2.71   2.82   1.11
7    pp  33.91  36.39  24.96  26.0  22.71  24.34  19.47
```

**Desired output:**
[image]

Any thoughts?

Comment: `result = le.fit_transform(result)`?

Comment: @AnuragDabas ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (8, 8) instead.
That's because the dataframe has 8 entries as rows.